# No response output from the GitHub API

Tags: express, github-api

```
    router.get('/github/:username', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const options = {
            uri: `https://api.github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos/per_page=5&sort=created:asc&
                  client_id=${config.get('githubClientId')}&client_secret=${config.get('githubClientSecret')}`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'user-agent': 'node.js' }
        };

        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) console.error(error);

            if (response.statusCode !== 200)
                res.status(404).json({ msg: "No user found" })

            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
```

I am using the Github api to fetch the latest 5 repos of a user.
No matter what username I give, I'm getting this error:

```
http_outgoing.js:536
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I'm getting "No User Found" output everytime.

Comment: [`request` is deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142). Use something else.

Comment: Woah! Didn't see that coming. What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: axios and node-fetch are popular.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub no longer allows us to create OAuth apps, instead you have to generate a Personal Access Token. Also I am using **axios**, since ***Request*** is deprecated.

```
const uri = encodeURI(
        `https://api.github.com/users/${req.params.username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc`
    );
    const headers = {
        'user-agent': 'node.js',
        Authorization: `token ${config.get('githubToken')}`
    };

    const gitHubResponse = await axios.get(uri, { headers });
    return res.json(gitHubResponse.data);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No Github profile found' });
}
```